# iOS Swift application: how to know total number of users currently logged in?

Tags: ios, swift

First of all, this may be a very immature question, but I need some solution!

I have an application in Swift language where multiple users can login and access the features.

There is a requirement to get a total number of users logged in at a particular instance. I know this could be achieved using Google Analytics. But is there any easy way do this?

Comment: Please don't simply down vote. If you know the answer is there in stack overflow, provide the link.

Answer (score 1):

Install Crashlytics in which you see the errors and also daily active users and many more things.

https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/

[image: See this image and more information appears when you click on charts]

Answer (score 0):

Use google analytics framework.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/

Answer (score -1):

Either you can use an analytics solution as you mentioned or if you can configure your own service to collect ping information from your app.
The app (considering it works always online) can ping the service in intervals of every 5 - 10 mins. Any user that hasn't pinged in that duration can be considered offline or is not running the app.